# Formula using Variables with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am wrestling with the syntax of this one line of some code. the formula with "IfError" seems to have the wrong syntax. I believe I have the quotes in the right places.

```
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim MidPointE As String
    Dim Dist As String
    Dim Allocation As String

    MidPointE = "AM"
    Dist = "AN"
    Allocation = "AO"

   for J= 1 to 300
     Cells(j, Dist).Formula = "=IFERROR(" & MidPointE & j & " / " & MidPointE &  CustomerLast & ", "")"
    Cells(j, Allocation).Formula = "=" & Allocation & j & "* S" & CustomerLast

     Next J
```

Comment: `& ", "")"` at the end should be `& ", """")"`

Comment: FWIW - `Cells(j, Allocation).Formula = "=" & Allocation & j & "* S" & CustomerLast` (after you assign a value to `CustomerLast`) is going to cause circular reference errors.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried that before but getting confirmation suddenly made it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also assign multiple formulas at the same time:

```
Range("AN1:AN300").Formula = "=IFERROR(AM1 / AM$" &  CustomerLast & ", """")"
Range("AO1:AO300").Formula = "=AO1 * S$" & CustomerLast
```

I also recommend looking into Excel Tables and [Structured References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb833052)

To avoid the circular reference issue, you can calculate the formulas and assign the values directly:

```
Range("AN1:AN300") = Evaluate("IFERROR(AM1:AM300 / AM$" &  CustomerLast & ", """")")
Range("AO1:AO300") = Evaluate("INDEX(AO1:AO300 * S$" & CustomerLast & ",)")
```

Comment: And that AO cell is still going to cause a circular reference - but only the OP can solve that.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318942/formula-using-variables-with-vba#comment81589145_47318942):

```
 Cells(j, Dist).Formula = "=IFERROR(" & MidPointE & j & " / " & MidPointE &  CustomerLast & ", """")"
```

Quotes inside a string literal must be escaped - and that's done by doubling them up.

Answer (score 0):

It's at the end here

```
& ", "")"
```

The two quotes between the comma and ) end the string and start a new one.

```
'first string
","

'second string
")"
```

Since you can't just throw two strings together like that, i would replace the two quotes with the CHR equivalent. Should look something like this:

```
Cells(j, Dist).Formula = "=IFERROR(" & MidPointE & j & " / " & MidPointE &  CustomerLast & ", "& CHR(034) & CHR(034) & ")"
'pretty sure 034 is the ascii code for "
```